# How can I check to see if my laptop is being"managed"

Tags: macbook-pro

I need help.  Files are being deleted from my laptop w/o my consent; I just discovered that my personal laptop is being "managed" - can someone help me find out how to put an end to this??  THanks.

Comment: You say "my" laptop. Is that my in you own it or is that my in supplied to you by your employer?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you be explicit what needs to end? The simple explanation of missing files is filesystem corruption but perhaps you have some more details you can share so we can assist

Answer (score 1):

### Mobile device management

This is the most common form of device management. Check in System Preferences → Profiles. If there is no Profiles button, there are no profiles installed and this option is not in use. If there are profiles present, check the details of the profiles for their capabilities.

### Remote management

A precursor to MDM, this is activated in a separate location: System Preferences → Sharing. Remote Management is one of the options and can be deactivated, along with other forms of remote connectivity to various parts of macOS.

### Other software

Plenty of other software can be installed on macOS and provide remote access. If you are worried about this sort of access, audit the processes running in Activity Monitor and/or perform a fresh install of macOS.

Comment: These are good things, but my odds on missing file causes are disk corruption and malware.

Comment: @bmike or even simpler, bad file synchronization, be it a shared iCloud account, dropbox or something else.